# Angular ng-repeat generate menu

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to ng-repeat a json to generate menu that look like this:

```
{
    "menu":[
        {"title":"Menu 1",
         "link":"http://google.com",
         "submenu": []
        },
        {"title":"Menu 2",
         "submenu": [{"title":"submenu 1", "link":"http://bing.com"}]
        }
    ]
}
```

The output should be something like this:

```
<a href="http://google.com">Menu 1</a>
<a href="javascript:;" submenu submenu-width="400">Menu 2</a>
```

I am trying to do it with this:

```
<a ng-repeat="data in data.menu">{{data.title}}</a>
```

But I am stuck at:

1. How to add in `submenu submenu-width="400"` when `submenu` array is not empty?
2. How to put `href` with the value of `javascript:;` when there is no `link` or when there is sub-menu?

Answer (score 0):

This is not exact but similar what you want

```
<div ng-repeat="data in data.menu">
    <a ng-if="data.submenu.length <= 0" ng-href="{{ data.link }}">
       {{data.title}}
    </a>
    <a ng-if="data.submenu.length > 0" href="javascript:;" 
            submenu submenu-width="400">
       {{data.title}}
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But that will create an extra div on every loop. How can I prevent that?

Comment: @user1995781, imho it is better to create a directive then. In directive you will have more control on element rendering.

Comment: Actually that whole `ng-repeat` is in the template of directive. How can that give me more control?

Comment: @user1995781 use "link" function of directive. It has an "element" parameter, which you can add attributes like "submenu" dynamically.

Comment: It would be nice if you can show an example how it can be done for better understanding. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-show to display the hyperlinks 
try,

```
 <div ng-repeat="data in data.menu" >
    <a ng-show=data.link href='{{data.link}}'>{{data.title}}</a>
    <a ng-show=!data.link href='javascript:;' submenu submenu-width="400">{{data.title}}</a>
</div>
```

here is the working plunker   [plkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/2m097ZmbQgfMF3iquEnR?p=preview)